# Questions on simple workings of C++?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I just have a few general questions about keeping code clean and readable.

1) Should functions have separate files from main (prototypes and initialization) ? (the functions are long)

2) If functions do have separate files, in Main do I include the function prototypes or the function initializations?

3) Are global variables in main shared across all files in the project? If not, how would I make it so the variable has access by all files?

4) If I include functions, when I use `#include` do I keep the function file names in `<>` or `""`? When would I use each one?

5) When including a function, do I just include its name, or its full address? (I am using Code Blocks). For example, if I am including a function file called calculate.hpp, would I do `#include "calculate.hpp"` or `#include "Users\Me\My Documents\calculate.hpp"`?

Comment: This is more like _How does c++ work_ rather than _Which is a better coding style_!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of questions!

> 1) Should functions have separate files from main (prototypes and initialization) ? (the functions are long)

Simplistically speaking:

- *Declarations* go in the header file (.h)
- *Definitions* go in the source file (.cpp)

If "the functions are long", consider how you can shorten them. Since you ask about keeping code clean, I recommend [*Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship* by Robert C. Martin](http://tinyurl.com/CleanCodeBook), which talks about this at length.

> 2) If functions do have separate files, in Main do I include the function prototypes or the function initializations?

You should only ever `#include` header files.

> 3) Are global variables in main shared across all files in the project? If not, how would I make it so the variable has access by all files?

Global variables should be the exception rather than the rule. However, see my earlier point about declaration and definition.

> 4) If I include functions, when I use #include do I keep the function file names in <> or ""? When would I use each one?

You're `#include`-ing  a whole file, not just a function.

- Use `<>` for system-wide headers, such as those in the standard library
- `""` for local headers, such as your own `calculate.hpp`.

> 5) When including a function, do I just include its name, or its full address? (I am using Code Blocks). For example, if I am including a function file called calculate.hpp, would I do #include "calculate.hpp" or #include "Users\Me\My Documents\calculate.hpp"?

Use relative paths (with forward-slashes where necessary), never absolute paths. Consider what happens when someone else tries to build your code.

I recommend checking out some open-source C++ projects on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net) or [GitHub](https://github.com/) to see how they're laid-out.

Comment: Thanks. Would I link the implementation in the declaration? Because other no file would have access to the implementation.

Comment: The definitions would need to be *linked*, yes.

Comment: and linking would be done with #include too?
Thanks

Comment: @user1017485: **No.** Linking would be done by the *[linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing))*

Answer (score 1):

Compiler should see declarations of the identifiers in the current translation unit what ever being used. With that said, since it is C++, let's think of member functions.

1. Yes, seperate the implementation from declaration ( templates is an exception where you can get around it too ).
2. Compiler should see the prototypes(declarations) of a specific member functions you are trying to invoke. So yes, it needs to see the prototypes and if it isn't defined in any where then linker bombs.
3. Global variables can be accessed across any source file provided the file specifies external linkage for the variable using the keyword `extern`.
4. Usually standard headers are enclosed in `<>`. If you have a user defined header then it is enclosed in `""`.
5. It depends. If your header resides in the current project directory specifying just the header file is sufficient. Or if it resides any where else, you need to provide full path to it's location.

Comment: Thanks. Would I link the implementation in the declaration? Because other no file would have access to the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends on specifics.
2. Create a header file for each group of functions.  `#include` it in all dependent modules plus the implementation module.
3. Global variables are available to any module that knows about them.  Typically they would be declared in the same module's header file as `extern`.
4. Use `#include <file.h>` for standard library files.  Use `#include "file.h"` for all others.  In most circumstances it is not advisable to give a path:  use the `-I` compiler command line option to list include directories.  This helps with build control and managing different compilation environments.
5. First of all, never use backslashes in a path.  Always use forward slashes.  Even on Windows.  See #4 for for the rest.

Comment: Thanks. Would I link the implementation in the declaration? Because other no file would have access to the implementation.